# Incorrect results while converting list of values to a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am working on a requirement to convert a list of values appended from a for loop to a dataframe and I can see the results have changed and I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please find the attached screenshot and requesting some help, Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The values are actually are correct and have no problem (look closely). The only noticeable mismatch is for `ScaledLR`; it should be zero, right? Nope, the first `print` is rounding to a certain number of decimal places, the number is so small (`8e-27`) that it shows up as `0.000000`. However, the dataframe isn't rounding, so it's showing a very small but true value. There is nothing wrong going on.

Comment: Hi Saed, Thanks for your reply. But when you look at ScaledEN and scaledKNN the values are different right, could you please confirm if there is some logic with which its calculating

Comment: That's incorrect. There's no difference. An `e+02` at the end of a value means the final value is whatever it says before multiplied by 10^2. e-27 means you'll have to multiply the value with 10^-27 to get the actual value.